# Need tool tip on userform command button

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need to pop up tool tip when user hovers over command button on a userform. I have tried to put the desired text in to ControlTip Text property of the command button but no tool tip appears during run time of the userform. Am I missing something? Is any event programming needed for this?

Comment: It works fine for me... Is the button disabled? Is there something covering it?

Comment: Working for me. Can try to a fresh new workbook for testing purpose.

Comment: I am opening files with the userform so am keeping the userform always on top of all windows, faced the problem with msgboxes being open on other file's windows so am using modal msgboxes...probably similar problem with tool tips...not sure

Comment: If the form is shown as modeless then the tool tip will not work if the form is not active. For it to work, the form needs to be in focus.

Comment: The form is modeless, even though I am actively using the controls on it, the tool tip doesn't show up on the buttons